# How do I get the target property of a dynamically created storyboard? My code just returns null

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

Storyboard.SetTargetProperty sets an animations target property, but a Storyboard.GetTargetProperty on the following line will return null.

The following code crashes on second-to-last line, 
    Storybard.SetTargetProperty(a, Storyboard.GetTargetProperty(a));
after DoubleAnimation a has been assigned a target property. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Removing that line produces a storyboard that animates the rectangle properly.

The full code is here:

For example,

```
public Storyboard moveDown(Rectangle rect){
//Set up the animation

DoubleAnimation a=new DoubleAnimation();
a.RepeatBehavior=new RepeatBehavior(1);
a.FillBehavior=FillBehavior.HoldEnd;
a.From=0;
a.To=100;
a.Duration=10;

//Set up the Storyboard
Storyboard sb=new Storyboard();
sb.Children.Add(a);
sb.Duration=a.Duration;

//Assign animation's target and property. This resulting animation works great.
Storyboard.SetTarget(a, rect);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(a, new PropertyPath(Canvas.TopProperty));

//Here's the problem: I can't get the propertypath back with GetTargetProperty
//targetProperty is null.
var targetProperty=Storyboard.GetTargetProperty(a);

//And this line crashes the program. It's only here for debugging purposes.
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(a, Storyboard.GetTargetProperty(a));

//You need to say canvas.Resources.Add("a unique id in quotes", sb) if you want it to  
//run on a canvas.

return sb;
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Just a random shot in the dark, but does this work? `Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(a, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.TopProperty)"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `PropertyPath` can be initialised with either a `DependencyProperty` or a `String`.  How the `Storyboard` handles a `PropertyPath` depends on how it has been initialised.

When `SetTargetProperty` is passed a `PropertyPath` that has been initialised with a `DependencyProperty` then it retrieves the `DependencyProperty` and discards the `PropertyPath`, it uses a different internal attached property to store this `DependencyProperty`.

Only when `SetTargetProperty` is assigned with a `PropertyPath` that has been initialised with a string does it actually set the attached property `TargetProperty`.

Unfortunately the `GetTargetProperty` simply returns the value of the `TargetProperty` regardless of how the counter-part `SetTargetProperty` behaves.  Hence `GetTargetProperty` will return `null` when `SetTargetProperty` has been called with a `PropertyPath` that was initialised with a `DependencyProperty` because the `TargetProperty` value never actually got set in the first place.

If you change your initialisation to this:-

```
 Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(a, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Top)"));
```

Then your code will work.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was incredible helpful.